# Flink LEAD LAG functions in Table API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-table-api

Hello i see in documentation that Flink support Lead Lag function
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/

But cant find how do apply in table api ?

```
  Table win = t
                .window(Over
                        .partitionBy($("userId"))
                        .orderBy($("userId"))
                        .as("w"))
                   .select($("userId"),  
                           $("count").lead(-1),  
                           $("count").lag(1));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows that there's a `LEAD` and `LAG` function in Flink SQL, but there is no implementation for them in the Table API. If you want to use these functions, you'll need to execute a SQL statement directly in your Table API application.

Something like:

```
tableEnv.executeSql(
  "INSERT INTO RubberOrders SELECT product, amount FROM Orders WHERE product LIKE '%Rubber%'");
```

But then with your necessary SQL statement of course :)

Comment: Hi. I tried your advice via SQL, but I still get an error. I created the corresponding question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127470/flink-sql-with-lag-function-nullpointerexception